# Identification of a Lepidopteran

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

I’m afraid the quality of the television picture below isn’t very good, but can anyone identify this moth? It was one of those that invaded the pitch at the Euro Final in Paris on 10th July 2016.

[image: Ronaldo's moth]

Comment: Let me know if my edits translate accurately, to your intentioned meanings

Comment: @hello_there_andy — No. Your English was — and is — deficient (intentioned meaning, indeed) and the general edit was poor. If the chatty style offended you and you felt it needed formal time and place I have dealt with this. I commend the revised question to you as an example of succinctness. If you have any further criticism please raise it and I will deal with it or not, but please do not vandalize my English. I am an Oxford educated native speaker.

Comment: Noted. And apologies. I enjoy the fact you changed it since :) OP. I will also respect your request to not edit your future work. But believe me, there are certain controls in place to ensure it is not entirely your property. Try deleting some of your answers, to play an example.

Comment: @hello_there_andy — I appreciate that questions and answers can be edited by others and understand that they are for the community as a whole. However as I spend considerable time correcting and improving questions from non-native or naive posters, I found your treatment of my question extremely irksome and that of whoever approved the change quite reprehensible.

Comment: I really do apologise. I also realise my English might need better practice. You helped me take proactive action to improve it (no sarcasm), TQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't watch the game, but from what I've seen on the internet it was the Silver Y (*Autographa gamma*), drawn there by the lights while migrating http://theconversation.com/moths-expert-match-report-on-ronaldo-insect-encounter-at-euro-2016-final-62314

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't really be completely sure by this picture alone so I did some [searching around](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/euro-2016-final-moths-cristiano-ronaldo-why-where-did-they-come-from-france-paris-swarm-a7131016.html) and turns out it is a [Autographa Gamma(Silver Y)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Y)

Comment: oh, you beat me to it by a second or something!

Comment: There is always place for more! Oh and by the way I didn't watch the game either. Was there some kind of "havoc" happening?

Comment: i really don't know, all i saw of it was the moth discussions trickling down into my usually sports-free circles.

Comment: @Ria — I wouldn't call it havok, but every time the play stopped and the camera zoomed in on a player there seemed to be at least one moth flying round him. And, of course, there was Ronaldo on the ground, in pain, in tears, waiting to be stretchered off, completely oblivious to the moth on his face — unlike the millions watching.

Comment: @picapica, actually Ria beat you to it by two mins :) - though, I'm not entirely sure why yours still "won"